# Can't use callback function AND easing plugin

Tags: jquery, callback

I can't get the following to work, totally breaks the page...  It works if I take out the callback function...  not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var easing = 'easeOutBounce';


$('#cont').click(function() {
    $('#cont').animate({width: '400px'}, {duration:1000, easing: easing, complete:function(){ $(this).html("Animation Completed");});
            $('#conttwo').animate({width: '100px'}, {duration:1000, easing: easing});
            $('#contthree').animate({width: '100px'}, {duration:1000, easing: easing});
});
```

Comment: JSFiddle? It's too hard to picture what happens.

Answer (score 0):

By default, jQuery only supports `swing` and `linear` easing. If you want to use more advanced easing functions, you need to include them from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

As an update, I should note that easeOutBounce does not appear to be provided by jQuery UI. You'll need to find an appropriate plug that provides it. A quick search suggests you can do it with the [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).